# How to reverse column order of a file in Linux from the command line

Tags: parsing, command-line, csv

I have a file named `ip-list` with two columns:

```
IP1  <TAB>  Server1
IP2  <TAB>  Server2
```

And I want to produce:

```
Server1  <TAB>  IP1
Server2  <TAB>  IP2
```

What's the most elegant, shortest Linux command line tool to do it?

Comment: Which platform? Windows, Unix, Max . . .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use awk:

```
awk '{print $2,$1}' ip-list
```

That should give you what you want.

Comment: It's worth noting that it gives the result as space-delimited, but it's rather trivial to insert the tab escape if you need it.

Comment: Working even on files with only one column (for scripts cases), but it will then put a space as first character in outputs.

Answer (score 7):

**More than two columns**

```
printf "\
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
" | awk '{for(i=NF;i>1;i--)printf "%s ",$i;printf "%s",$1;print ""}'
```

Output:

```
4 3 2 1
8 7 6 5
```

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46275/swapping-an-unlimited-number-of-columns

Tested in GNU Awk 4.0.1.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is:

```
awk '{print $2 "\t" $1}'
```

However, there are some issues.  If there may be white space in either of the fields, you need to do one of: (depending on if your awk supports -v)

```
awk -v FS='\t' '{print $2 "\t" $1}'
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="\t" } {print $2 "\t" $1}'
```

Alternatively, you can do one of:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $2,$1}'
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS="\t" } {print $2,$1}'
awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' '{print $2,$1}' # if allowing spaces in fields
```

One of the comments asks, 'where does the filename go'?  awk is used as a filter, so it would typically appear as:

```
$ some-cmd | awk ... | other-cmd
```

with no filename given.  Or, a filename can be given as an argument after all commands:

```
$ awk ... filename
```

Answer (score 1):

`perl -pi -e 's/^([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)$/\2\t\1/' yourfile.csv`

`perl -pi -e 'split("\t"); print "$_[1]\t$_[0]"'`

The first one probably works on `sed`, too.

Comment: Perl has a reverse() function, which will reverse a string, array, or number, so you'd just reverse the results of a split call, then join again.