# How to reverse order of fields using AWK?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a file with the following layout:

```
123,01-08-2006
124,01-09-2007
125,01-10-2009
126,01-12-2010
```

How can I convert it into the following by using AWK?

```
123,2006-08-01
124,2007-09-01
125,2009-10-01
126,2009-12-01
```

Comment: I reworded your question, and decided to alter wording of "reverse a string".  What you do is not reversing a string, but reversing the order of fields, separated by non-word characters.  Feel free to propose a better wording if I guessed what's your aim incorrectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegant way to reverse column order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227986/elegant-way-to-reverse-column-order)

Answer (score 4):

Didn't read the question properly the first time. You need a field separator that can be either a dash or a comma. Once you have that you can use the dash as an output field separator (as it's the most common) and fake the comma using concatenation:

```
awk -F',|-' 'OFS="-" {print $1 "," $4,$3,$2}' file
```

Comment: he wants to reorder the date field

Answer (score 2):

Pure awk

```
awk -F"," '{ n=split($2,b,"-");$2=b[3]"-"b[2]"-"b[1];$i=$1","$2 } 1' file
```

sed

```
sed -r 's/(^.[^,]*,)([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/\1\4-\3-\2/' file
sed 's/\(^.[^,]*,\)\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9]\+\)/\1\4-\3-\2/' file
```

Bash

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="," read -r a b
do
  IFS="-"
  set -- $b
  echo "$a,$3-$2-$1"
done <"file"
```

Comment: Hi i am getting the below error while executing

"sed: illegal option -- r"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think standard `awk` only allows one field separator character so you'll have to pre-process the data. You can do this with `tr` but if you really want an `awk`-only solution, use:

```
pax> echo '123,01-08-2006
124,01-09-2007
125,01-10-2009
126,01-12-2010' | awk -F, '{print $1"-"$2}' | awk -F- '{print $1","$4"-"$3"-"$2}'
```

This outputs:

```
123,2006-08-01
124,2007-09-01
125,2009-10-01
126,2010-12-01
```

as desired.

The first `awk` changes the `,` characters to `-` so that you have four fields separated with the same character (this is the bit I'd usually use `tr ',' '-'` for).

The second `awk` prints them out in the order you specified, correcting the field separators at the same time.

If you're using an `awk` implementation that allows multiple `FS` characters, you can use something like:

```
gawk -F ',|-' '{print $1","$4"-"$3"-"$2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be awk, you could use Perl too:

```
$ perl -nle 'print "$1,$4-$3-$2" while (/(\d{3}),(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})\s*/g)' < file.txt
```