# Linux shell command to reverse the field order of varying length text records

Tags: linux, shell, parsing, reverse, command-line-interface

I would like a command line incantation to reverse the field order of arbritrary length text records. Solutions provided in [Rearrange columns using cut](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2129123/250097) and [Elegant way to reverse column order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1227986/250097) don't solve this issue since they assume a fixed amount of fields, though maybe they would with minor changes.

Sort of like the `tac` command that exhibits reverse `cat` functionality. I'd like what the `ohce` command would do (if it existed) to reverse `echo` functinality.

For example:

```
a b c d
e f
g h i
```

Should be transformed to

```
d c b a
f e
i h g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a command to do it, it's named `rev` from [util-linux](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) :

```
$ rev file
d c b a
f e
i h g
```

or using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ perl -lane 'print join " ", reverse @F' file
d c b a
f e
i h g
```

But like you explain in the comments, if you want the 3 latest columns, you can use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '{print $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}' file
```

Comment: `rev` reverses characters, so a line like `abc def` would appear as `fed cba`. The question is ambiguous, so @chiam will have to clarify.

Comment: With this two solutions, OP have the choice, they treat both cases.

Comment: Fixed perl version by adding newlines for each lines

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, but the fact that rev reverses all the characters doesn't affect its usefulness for me, just apply it again. `echo` give me the last three fields | `rev` | (`read` a b c ignore the rest; `echo` $a $b $c) | `rev`

Comment: See my `awk` solution if you want the 3 latest columns.

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
awk '{for (i=NF; i>1; i--) printf "%s%s", $i, FS; print $i }' file
d c b a
f e
i h g
```

Answer (score 1):

with bash:

```
while read -ra words; do 
    for ((i=${#words[@]}-1; i>=0; i--)); do 
        printf "%s " "${words[i]}"
    done
    echo
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/):

```
echo 'a b c d
e f          
g h i' | datamash --no-strict -t' ' reverse
```

Output:

```
d c b a
f e
i h g
```

Unlike `rev`, it doesn't reverse words:

```
echo 'abc xyz' | datamash --no-strict -t' ' reverse
```

Output:

```
xyz abc
```