# How to find a matching word in a file and print the words of that line in reverse order in unix using script?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I am trying to solve a problem in which I am given a few lines for eg:

```
abdkfsj | kfjlds | james
sdlfjk | sfdjsldfjk | andrew
sdjfsdl | dskljoer | james
```

I was asked to find the lines which contain james and print them in reverse order the output of above example will be-

```
james | kfjlds | abdkfsj
james | dskljoer | sdjfsdl
```

Can someone please tell me how to solve this and what command will be used to solve this question in unix using shell scripting?

Tried this:

```
awk -F"|" '{ print $3 $2 $1}' | grep --line-buffered james input.txt
```

Comment: I don't understand how to solve this I had tried grep command with awk

Comment: awk -F"|" '{ print $3 $2 $1}' | grep --line-buffered james input.txt

Comment: Better [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54615218/edit) into your question :)

Comment: In both your input and output examples you show a _space_ character on each side of the _pipe_ character, so is the delimiter _space_ | _space_ or is it just `|`? If you added the _space_ for clarity you should note that! Samples of _input_ and _output_ should always be shown as explicitly what is and what is expected!

Comment: It's better to give us some feedback, instead of just ask a question and leave it there, if you are too busy then come when you have reasonably enough time for it. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and [someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Actually "|" is delimiter, I had put space just to make the input and o/p shows clearly here that's it In actual there is no space only "|" seperate the words   @user3439894

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/james/{for (i=NF; i>1; i--) printf "%s%s", $i, FS; print $i}' file
```

If line contains `james` output its columns in reverse order.

Output:

```
james | kfjlds | abdkfsj
james | dskljoer | sdjfsdl
```

---

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21944886/3776858

Comment: A restriction: my code won't work if columns contain spaces or tabs: `abdkfsj | kfjlds | james smith`

Comment: Without this restriction and GNU awk: `awk -v FS=' \\| ' -v OFS=" | " '/james/{for (i=NF; i>1; i--) printf "%s%s", $i, OFS; print $i}' file`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are on the right way actually, just needs to set `OFS`, also add the condition:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" '/james/{print $3,$2,$1}' input.txt
```

So with this one command you can do the thing, no need to pipe to grep.

And if there're many columns to reverse:

```
awk -F'|' '/james/{for(i=1;i<=NF/2;i++){j=NF-i+1;t=$i;$i=$j;$j=t}print}' OFS='|' input.txt
```

Here I used a different approach by actually exchange high columns with low columns, and by assigning `OFS` before the input files, saved the necessity of `-v`.

Well, if you want to **keep the spaces too**, use these `GNU awk` solutions:

```
awk -F' *[|] *' -v OFS=' | ' '/james/{print $3,$2,$1}' input.txt
james | kfjlds | abdkfsj
james | dskljoer | sdjfsdl

$ awk -F' *[|] *' '/james/{for(i=1;i<=NF/2;i++){j=NF-i+1;t=$i;$i=$j;$j=t}print}' OFS=' | ' input.txt
james | kfjlds | abdkfsj
james | dskljoer | sdjfsdl
```

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for mention it, I already noticed that, however I thought that was just added by OP to better show the data. If you check OP's own code you can see OP's purpose.

Comment: @user3439894 Anyway, what exactly OP wants only OP knows, so long OP don't show up and communicate, we can't be sure. And I think we answer questions on SO is to help OPs(and others, including ourselves) improve, not just do their work. So as long as my answers can give someone insights, I think it's enough. Btw, just fyi, not that it's important, it's me first upvoted Cyrus's answer.

Comment: @user3439894  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the grep command to be given as input to the awk is incorrect. It needs little tweaking and adding OFS="|" in the BEGIN does the job. Check this out

```
 awk -F"|" 'BEGIN { OFS="|"} { print $3,$2,$1}' <(grep --line-buffered james divesh.txt)
```

with the inputs.

```
$ cat divesh.txt
abdkfsj | kfjlds | james
sdlfjk | sfdjsldfjk | andrew
sdjfsdl | dskljoer | james

$ awk -F"|" 'BEGIN { OFS="|"} { print $3,$2,$1}' <(grep --line-buffered james divesh.txt)
 james| kfjlds |abdkfsj
 james| dskljoer |sdjfsdl

$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try sed :

```
sed '/james/s/\([^|]*\)\( *| *\)\([^|]*\)\2\([^|]*\)/\4 \2\3\2\1/' infile
```